# Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

this was myis piece of code. I have this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   private.xml /private/res/layout line 12 Android AAPT Problem

```
<LinearLayout android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:id="@+id/configure_cancel_button"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" 
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_selector" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/configure_confirm_button"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" 
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/confirm_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wich line is line 12 in `/private/res/layout/private.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

First line is incorrect.

`<LinearLayout android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Should be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Remove the "android:" before the "xmlns"

Comment: Another thing I'd like to note is that this kind of an issue is easily solvable by using the XML generating ability of IDEs (e.g. Eclipse, Android Studio).
Even If you wouldn't actually use the generated code, it's good for comparing your code to as you know the templates they provide has to be in correct syntax.